# Zend framework, add index controller and index action names to URL

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I need to add the index controller name and the index action name in the url
for example:

application.local  will display the  application.local/index/index (index controller, index action)
In the url I need to display the full path: application.local/index/index

and

application.local/pages  will display application.local/pages/index -I need to display the full path in the url: application.local/pages/index

It's like a 301 redirect, but I want to know if there is a possibility to do this form the framework and not form htaccess

Comment: bububaba's answer will work, but can you explain why you are needing this to occur in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

One way to address this would be inspecting the URL (i.e. `$request->getServer('REQUEST_URI')`) and the dispatched controller and action (`$request->getControllerName()`, `$request->getActionName()`) to see if your criteria for redirecting are met. If so - do a redirect.

A good place to put this logic would be a FrontController plugin.